# Weblogic : node in cluster shuts down, no JMS message is sent

Tags: weblogic

I have a weblogic cluster which has 4 nodes (managed servers). Today I found two of them are down, and I found in suprise that some JMS messages are not sent.

I wonder if it's the normal behaviour ? Shouldn't the cluster continue to deliver JMS using the two available nodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reach high availability for JMS you should configure two things

1. Migratable targets.
2. Persistance based either on shared storage or a database.

**Why migratable targets?** This is because messages produced by i.e. JMSServer01 can only be processed by JMSServer01. Thus, when you configure migratable targets the JMSServer01 will be migrated automatically into another Weblogic server.

**Why persistance based on shared storage or a database?** This is because once the JMS Server is migrated into another server, it will try to process the messages, which must be in a shared storage or database that can be seen by all your Weblogic servers.

You can find more information here https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/ASHIA/jmsjta.htm#ASHIA4396